# Is there an easy way to keep meshes in one piece when uv unwrapping?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I am trying to add a wrap design to a model in blender. I assume uv mapping is the easiest way to do that, however when I unwrap my surfaces, the meshes are getting split up instead of staying in one whole shape. Is there any easy way to get the meshes to project as the single surface that they are projected from?

[image]

I basically just want to flatten the mesh in order to easily scale it to the wrap template. Also, the model is a 3DM file imported from rhino.

Comment: you could try a project from view from the right point and do the rest manually. But only project for the part that lines up don't select your whole mesh and then do it from every angle

Comment: I tried project from view but then it is not true to the flattened shape. I was using that and scaling the mesh and then adjusting the shape but it warped the image on the 3d model.

Comment: Okay, you probably have to add your seams manually. Go to the UV Editing space and put the seams there where the texture would be cut. If you don't know how just google for a basic tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just marked all of the edges of each surface as seams but it isn't keeping the mesh together. Is there a way to remesh everything?

Comment: Hello, Julia :). Manual unwrapping seems like the best way here. But marking edge seams everywhere is seldom useful. Perhaps try to watch a few tutorials on unwrapping, it'll save you a lot of time (and hair pulling) :).

Comment: Thanks Jachym! I have watched a lot of videos but haven't really found what I am looking for...is there any way to just project an image onto the model and then move it around almost like a decal? I feel like this should be a lot easier than it is turning out to be.

Comment: Also relevant, sometimes imported models have lots of vertices that are in the same position as each other, so it is actually split up. Select all, and use “merge by distance“ to check for this.

Comment: Merge by distance seemed to be the key, thank you!!